# NestJS Prisma - Types of property entities incompatible, missing or not assigned

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to update my Postgres database using Prisma ORM in NestJS (Microservices architecture).
The code allows users to interact with invitation requests.
But I keep getting the error:
`Argument of type 'Invitation' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Invitation & { work: Work; }'. Property 'work' is missing in type 'Invitation' but required in type '{ work: Work; }'`.

The Full error message looks like this:

`Type '{ status: "PENDING" | "ACCEPTED" | "REJECTED"; work: undefined; id: string; workId: string; coId?: string; createdAt: Date; respondedAt?: Date; owner?: string; note?: string; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<InvitationUpdateInput, InvitationUncheckedUpdateInput> & InvitationUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & InvitationUpdateInput)'.`

`Type '{ status: "PENDING" | "ACCEPTED" | "REJECTED"; work: undefined; id: string; workId: string; coId?: string; createdAt: Date; respondedAt?: Date; owner?: string; note?: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<InvitationUncheckedUpdateInput, InvitationUpdateInput> & InvitationUpdateInput'.`

`Type '{ status: "PENDING" | "ACCEPTED" | "REJECTED"; work: undefined; id: string; workId: string; coId?: string; createdAt: Date; respondedAt?: Date; owner?: string; note?: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<InvitationUncheckedUpdateInput, InvitationUpdateInput>'. Types of property 'workId' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

The Invitation Interface:

```
export default class Invitation {
  id: string; 
  workId: string; 
  work: string;
  co?: string;
  status: RequestStatus;
  createdAt: Date;
  respondedAt?: Date;
  owner?: string;
  note?: string;
}

export enum RequestStatus {
  PENDING = 'PENDING',
  REJECTED = 'REJECTED',
  ACCEPTED = 'ACCEPTED',
}
```

The prisma invitation schema:

```
model Invitation {
  id              String        @id @db.Uuid
  workId          String        @db.Uuid
  work            Work          @relation(...)
  status          RequestStatus
  co              String        @db.Uuid
  owner           String
  note            String  
  createdAt       DateTime
  respondedAt     DateTime  
}
```

The Updating mechanics in Postgres Persistence Infrastructure:

```
  async update(invitation: Invitation): Promise<Invitation> {
    const entity = await this.prismaService.invitation.update({
      where: {
        id: invitation.id,
      },
      data: {
        ...invitation,
        status: RequestStatusEntity[invitation.status],
        work: undefined,
      },
      include: {
        work: true,
      },
    });

    return this.toDomain(entity);
  }

  private toDomain(
    entity: InvitationEntity & {
      work: WorkEntity;
    },
  ): Invitation {
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(
      {
        ...entity,
        status: RequestStatus[entity.status],
      },
      Invitation.prototype,
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the model definition of Work in your schema.prisma file?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use TypeScript enums in this case as Prisma uses string literals in the generated type.

I would suggest using Prisma's types directly instead of creating your own like this:

```
import { RequestStatus } from '@prisma/client'

export default class Invitation {
  id: string; 
  workId: string; 
  work: string;
  co?: string;
  status: RequestStatus;
  createdAt: Date;
  respondedAt?: Date;
  owner?: string;
  note?: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you plaese take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71730018/how-to-use-enum-in-both-prisma-model-and-nestjs-graphql-sdl-first

The class which uses this enum is a generated one by Nestjs GraphQL system. Any idea to solve this enum issues?