# How to use enum in both Prisma model and Nestjs GraphQL SDL first

Tags: enums, graphql, nestjs, prisma

I'm using Prisma in NestJS GraphQL SDL first app. Prisma model lokks like;

```
enum Continent {
  Asia
  Europe
  America
  Africa
}

model Country {
  id         Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String          @unique()
  continent  Continent       @map("continent")
  City       City[]
  population Int?
  treaties   CountryTreaty[]


  @@map("country")
}
```

When I run the Prisma migration, it creates **Country** table with **continent** field of **Continent** type very nicely.

My **country.graphql** schema is like;

```
enum Continent {
  Asia
  Europe
  America
  Africa
  Australia
}

type Country {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  population: Int
  cities: [City!]
  treaties: [Treaty!]
  capital: City
  continent: Continent!
  abbr: String
}
```

and generated typings.ts is like;

```
export enum Continent {
    Asia = "Asia",
    Europe = "Europe",
    America = "America",
    Africa = "Africa",
    Australia = "Australia"
}

export class Country {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    population?: Nullable<number>;
    cities?: Nullable<City[]>;
    treaties?: Nullable<Treaty[]>;
    capital?: Nullable<City>;
    continent: Continent;
    abbr?: Nullable<string>;
}
```

My country service has findAll method which uses Prisma service;

```
  async findAll(name?: string) {
    if (name) {
      return await this.prisma.country.findMany({
        where: {
          name: {
            contains: name,
          },
        },
      });
    } else {
      return await this.prisma.country.findMany();
    }
  }
```

Finally, query resolver is;

```
  @Query()
  async countries(
    @Args('name', { nullable: true }) name?: string,
  ): Promise<Country[]> {
    return await this.countryService.findAll(name);
  }
```

At this point, countries resolver complains about the **Continent** enum;

```
Type 'import("E:/git/dev.to/hotchocolate-apollo-federation/country-subgraph/node_modules/.prisma/client/index").Country[]' is not assignable to type 'import("e:/git/dev.to/hotchocolate-apollo-federation/country-subgraph/src/graphql").Country[]'.
  Type 'import("E:/git/dev.to/hotchocolate-apollo-federation/country-subgraph/node_modules/.prisma/client/index").Country' is not assignable to type 'import("e:/git/dev.to/hotchocolate-apollo-federation/country-subgraph/src/graphql").Country'.
    Types of property 'continent' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("E:/git/dev.to/hotchocolate-apollo-federation/country-subgraph/node_modules/.prisma/client/index").Continent' is not assignable to type 'import("e:/git/dev.to/hotchocolate-apollo-federation/country-subgraph/src/graphql").Continent'.ts(2322)
```

Apparently, the two continents, in prisma client and in generated graphql.ts are not assignable each other!

What should I do differently not to make the resolver complain about this Continent enum?

Comment: Can you share what your GraphQL `ObjectType` looks like? From the code you shared, I'm guessing that you do have one called `Country`, used in the return type of your query

Comment: Since I'm using SDL first, I didn't create an ObjectType. I'm generating the typing in graphql.ts file. Continent enum & Country class were generated like I put above. Should I still create an ObjectType in SDL first?

Comment: Could you find a solution for this?

Comment: not really. Prisma apparently is not a best option to be used with NestJS. Using TypeORM. Much more reasonable...

Comment: It's probably not relevant anymore, but your enums are not the same. The Prisma enum does not have Australia and as such typescript is right that the two types are not compatible